# Hiding button in Tkinter before progress bar

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to hide the button before the progress bar starts loading, I have tried various methods but the button hides only after the progress bar has completed loading.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
import time
from pdf2docx import Converter
import os


# Functions
def load_next_screen(filetype, type_no):
    btn2.destroy()
    btn3.destroy()
    btn4.destroy()
    btn5.destroy()
    btn6.destroy()
    btn1.place(x=157.5, y=450)
    if filetype == "pdf":
        btn1.config(text="Upload a PDF file", width=25, command=lambda: open_file_dialog("pdf", type_no))
    elif filetype == "word":
        btn1.config(text="Upload a WORD file", width=25, command=lambda: open_file_dialog("word", type_no))
    else:
        btn1.config(text="Upload a Json file", width=25, command=lambda: open_file_dialog("json", type_no))


def open_file_dialog(filetype, type_no):
    if filetype == "pdf":
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select a PDF file", filetypes=[("PDF files", "*.pdf")])
        if file_path:
            if type_no == 1:
                pdftoword(file_path)
            else:
                pdftojson(file_path)
        else:
            file_status_label.config(text="No file selected please select again")
            btn1.config(text="Select Again!")
    elif filetype == "word":
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select a WORD file", filetypes=[("Word Documents", "*.docx")])
        if file_path:
            if type_no == 1:
                wordtopdf(file_path)
            else:
                wordtojson(file_path)
        else:
            file_status_label.config(text="No file selected please select again")
            btn1.config(text="Select Again!")
    else:
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select a JSON file", filetypes=[("JSON Files", "*.json")])
        if file_path:
            if type_no == 1:
                jsontopdf(file_path)
            else:
                jsontoword(file_path)
        else:
            file_status_label.config(text="No file selected please select again")
            btn1.config(text="Select Again!")


def show_loading_bar():
    loading_bar = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient="horizontal", length=300, mode="determinate")
    loading_bar.start()
    loading_bar.place(x=262.5, y=400, anchor="center")
    for i in range(101):
        loading_bar["value"] = i
        root.update_idletasks()
        time.sleep(0.05)
    loading_bar.stop()
    loading_bar.place_forget()
    file_status_label.config(text="File uploaded Successfully")
    file_status_label.place_forget()


def hide_button():
    btn1.place_forget()


def pdftoword(filepath):
    hide_button()
    file_status_label.config(text=f"Uploading selected file :{filepath}")
    file_status_label.place(x=262.5, y=450, anchor="center")
    show_loading_bar()
    
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("File Convertor Widget")
root.geometry("525x725")
root.resizable(True, True)

# Choice Buttons
btn1 = tk.Button(root, text="PDF to WORD", width=15, height=5, command=lambda: load_next_screen("pdf", 1))
btn1.place(x=50, y=450)

btn2 = tk.Button(root, text="PDF to JSON", width=15, height=5, command=lambda: load_next_screen("pdf", 2))
btn2.place(x=50, y=575)

btn3 = tk.Button(root, text="WORD to PDF", width=15, height=5, command=lambda: load_next_screen("word", 1))
btn3.place(x=200, y=450)

btn4 = tk.Button(root, text="WORD to JSON", width=15, height=5, command=lambda: load_next_screen("word", 2))
btn4.place(x=200, y=575)

btn5 = tk.Button(root, text="JSON to PDF", width=15, height=5, command=lambda: load_next_screen("json", 1))
btn5.place(x=350, y=450)

btn6 = tk.Button(root, text="JSON to WORD", width=15, height=5, command=lambda: load_next_screen("json", 2))
btn6.place(x=350, y=575)

file_status_label = tk.Label(root, width=60)

root.mainloop()
```

I have tried this and it doesn't seem to work, I get this problem when I call for the `pdftoword()` function, doesn't matter where I have written the `btn.place_forget()` it still hides only after once the loading bar has completed loading.

Comment: where is the rest ofthe code.  the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: as asked I have added the rest of the code in my above question.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by adding `root.update()` after you hide the button like this:

```py
def pdftoword(filepath):
    hide_button()
    root.update()
    file_status_label.config(text=f"Uploading selected file :{filepath}")
    file_status_label.place(x=262.5, y=450, anchor="center")
    show_loading_bar()
```

This is because, for a function triggered by a `tkinter` button event, the window doesn't update until you exit the triggered function.

Calling `update()` forces the window to process the widget edits like hiding the button.

This unwanted behavior can be replicated with this simple MRE:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Button
from time import sleep

def wait(): sleep(5)

root = Tk()
Button(root, text="click me", command=wait).grid()
root.mainloop()
```

In this example, clicking the button triggers a lambda function that waits 5 seconds. During this time, the button stays pressed.
After the 5 seconds have passed, `mainloop()` processes the events again and sees that the button is no longer clicked.

Here, we can solve the issue in the same way by editing the `wait` function:

```py
def wait():
    root.update()
    sleep(5)
```

I will link the reason why this is happening if I find it in the documentation, but I think that this behavior comes from the fact that the call to `mainloop()` happens in the main thread.